# Node js single threaded or multi-threaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, node-modules, async.js

many of them saying that node js is single threaded, but it process callback functions parallely during other process. as per my assumption single thread can handle only one instruction at a time. so how it process asynchroniously many instructions at a time?

Comment: I like that discussion about the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028377/is-it-possible-to-achieve-multithreading-in-nodejs

Comment: it is single thread and event-driven architecture. The callback functions are not parallel rather event-driven.Lots of articles are there please have a look

Comment: Node runs a single JavaScript thread with an event loop, plus a thread pool for certain (non-JS) tasks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,
Nodejs is single threaded but internally uses libuv library
https://github.com/libuv/libuv

Which is written on c++ and uses thread pooling concept in case if I/O or File system operation and having internal workers for same.

you may go through link to know about deep

https://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was useful :)