# How would you stop this expensive code from blocking other user request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  
  setImmediate( () = {
    heavyTask();
  });

  function heavyTask(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

I set up 2 users (userA, userB) in local dev. Whenever I use userA to trigger this function, other users like userB has to wait in line although these users are performing simpler task that takes a few ms. I'm definitely misunderstood something about setImmediate. I thought it's supposed to prevent blocking of event loop so other users don't have to wait in line when other users do expensive calculation.

The answer I'm looking for is **by example** using this code above.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028377/is-it-possible-to-achieve-multithreading-in-nodejs

Comment: Well, you can make it asynchronous. I would also like to ask what is that nested for loop doing? Maybe there is room for optimization.

Comment: `setImmediate` will allow other tasks to execute before this one but once this task is running, it's still blocking the thread. If you were to run something like this, then at best you can have every iteration's logic run in a `setImmediate`/`setTimeout`. In that case `heavyTask` would still need about the same processing time but if another task comes up, it will not be blocked: different task is put on the queue -> `heavyTask` will finish the current iteration and put the next iteration on the queue -> the different task is picked up and processed -> `heavyTask` is next on the queue again.

Comment: @vivek_23 It's a game event that calculate results based on player input and sends it back as json object. All  calculations are done within the function. It's a mixed of for loop and math calculations. I would try doing promise in my next test if it will work.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, I will try experimenting with that.

Comment: you could maybe use worker threads? could this fit to your app?

Comment: @Ifaruki Yeah, that will be one of my last resort. It it's really bad, I will just dump the function in Lambda in AWS.

Comment: Maybe `fork` can help? Move for loops in app.js and then do something like this: 

   `const cp = require('child_process');

    const task = cp.fork(__dirname + "/app.js");

    task.on('close', () => {
        //response here 
    })`

Comment: @IvanPenga I decided to just separate the function in lambda. After reading a few articles, I concluded its ideal to avoid heavy task in node.js in itself.